# how do i write a proper inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to merge two table records in one query using the inner join syntax.

```
table one

Unique_ID | School | Paid | Balance | Date  |
+---------+--------+------------- --+-------+
 112     MaryGold   200     500    2/5/19 
 112     MaryGold   300     200    9/5/19 
 107      MyKids    100     500    9/5/19 
 107      MyKids    100     400    2/6/19


and table two

Unique_ID | School | amountperterm | Academic_Year | Term | c_Paid | c_Balance |
+---------+--------+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-----------+
 112     MaryGold       700          2019 / 2020     1     500        200
 107      MyKids        600          2019 / 2020     1     200        400
```

table one shows records of every single payment made and balance remained
table two shows records of sum of all payments made and balance remained
I want a join query where by a school record in table 2 will be linked to all of its records of payments in table 1.

I am using jasper report to print out all school records with their respective bills..

 this code works where by a school record is selected in Jtable and the print_button is pressed.

```
int row = s_ThirdTerm.getSelectedRow();
            try{
            String table_click=(s_ThirdTerm.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());    
            JasperDesign jd =JRXmlLoader.load("printOuts\\ucmasReciept.jrxml");
            String sgl="select school_info.Unique_ID,school_info.School,school_info.amountperterm,school_info.Academic_Year,school_info.Term,school_info.currentallpaid,school_info.currentbalance,school_info.currentdate,school_bill_archive.Paid,\n" +
            "school_bill_archive.Balance,school_bill_archive.Date from school_bill_archive INNER JOIN school_info on school_info.Term=school_bill_archive.Term and school_info.Unique_ID=school_bill_archive.Unique_ID and school_info.School='"+table_click+"'";
            JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
            newQuery.setText(sgl);
            jd.setQuery(newQuery);
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            }
```

it displays the selected school in table 2 and all records of its bill payments from table 1. 
 
but I want a situation where I will not select a particular school but when I hit on the print_button, jasper report should open with records of all schools and their respective records of payment. 
 
 Eg. if I have 5 schools in table 2, I should have 5 pages in jasper report when I press the print_button. each page with a school's info from table 2 and its respective payments from table 1 .
this is the code I wrote but all it does is to display only a page with records from the first row in table 2 and all records from table 1.

```
            try{

            JasperDesign jd =JRXmlLoader.load("printOuts\\Reciept.jrxml");
            String sgl="select school_info.Unique_ID,school_info.School,school_info.amountperterm,school_info.Academic_Year,school_info.Term,school_info.currentallpaid,school_info.currentbalance,school_info.currentdate,school_bill_archive.Paid,\n" +
            "school_bill_archive.Balance,school_bill_archive.Date from school_bill_archive INNER JOIN school_info on school_info.Term=school_bill_archive.Term and school_info.Unique_ID=school_bill_archive.Unique_ID and school_info.School=school_bill_archive.School";
            JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
            newQuery.setText(sgl);
            jd.setQuery(newQuery);
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the tables' structure as `CREATE TABLE` statements, some sample data as  `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data. As your question currently stands it isn't clear what it is actually about.

Comment: why would school_info have a "Term" attribute?  My first guess, your tables are not laid out properly.  But you do need to show us table structure if you want help.

Comment: Why do you expect this query to *filter payments for a particular school*? Where is that *particular school* in your query?

Comment: the query is supposed link all schools and their respective payments done within a term.

Comment: And if you are referencing the school_info, in the school_bill_archive, why is the join not on the school_info.Unique_ID?

Comment: you should put some data to create the example set. It is not totally clear. 
If you want the total payment then you need to use SUM(school_bill_archive.Paid) and at the end of the query, you need to group by the school_info.Unique_ID like GROUP BY  school_info.Unique_ID, and please use ALIAS, please google how to make ALIAS and keep lines shorter

Comment: because I tried with the Unique_ID and still same results @Agapwlesu

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table.

Comment: Also, please use aliases on each joined table. It makes the query much more readable.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve and what your problem is. I think it would be best, you showed some sample data for the two tables and the expected result. Does `school_info` contain one row per school? Or can there be several rows for one school in the table? Do you want one row per school in the results or several? Do you want to show all schools, a particular one or some matching a certain condition?

Comment: table one has records of school names. so 5 records means 5 different schools. table two has records of school payments. each row holds records of a single payment. so a school can have multiple number of rows for different payments done. I want a join such that a school record will be linked to either a single or multiple number payments from table 2. either by Unique_ID or School_Name @ThorstenKettner

Comment: (Rhetorical:) Again: Where is our "cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output"? What is some code that does what you expect, and your statement of what you want to do to or extract from it to get the next partial result you want, and what is the extended code you tried that is wrong? Where is your statement, for each base table & the desired result, of what a row in it says about the situation? (Instead of your fragments of description. Also it is not helpful to try to say what you want by vaguely describing code.) Where are your edits, not comments, to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to see all payments for a particular school, you need to add filter to your query as below-

```
SELECT
<columns>
FROM school_info si
INNER JOIN school_bill_archive sba
ON si.Unique_ID = sba.Unique_ID -- This should be the joining key
WHERE si.Unique_ID = XX -- Replace XX with desire Unique ID
AND si.term = '<Put Term Value>'-- You can also filter by particular term if required
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but its joining a school record with all payments done by all schools @mkRabbani

Comment: table one has records of school names. so 5 records means 5 different schools. table two has records of school payments. each row holds records of a single payment. so a school can have multiple number of rows for different payments done. I want a join such that a school record will be linked to either a single or multiple number payments from table 2. either by Unique_ID or School_Name @mkRabbani

Comment: Joining on "si.Unique_ID = sba.Unique_ID" should give your expected output. It should only return your expected result. Can you post some sample data from both table?

Comment: please I have updated my question with the sample data @mkRabbani

Comment: @RodneyNart Can you please also add your expected output from those tables?

Comment: Things are getting more complex now as I am not aware how Jasper report actually works. I just can help if you provide data you are expecting from those table using Query.